# How to use text-wrap for ion-card in Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic2

**THE SITUATION**:

I need to use the `text-wrap` for an ion-card but it seems it doesn't work.

**THE CODE**:

```
<ion-card>

    <ion-card-header text-wrap>

        <h2> <ion-icon name="list-box"></ion-icon> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labor</h2>

    </ion-card-header>

    <ion-card-content>

        <p>content</p>

    </ion-card-content>

</ion-card>
```

**THE PLUNKER**:

http://plnkr.co/edit/z5ehOQgz0oArhg6mMtUj?p=preview

**THE QUESTION**:

There is a way to use text-wrap for the ion-card?

Comment: your plunker wasn't saved I guess? It's just a default tabs plunker

Comment: oh gosh. sorry! I have updated it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, setting `white-space: normal;` to the `ion-card-header` fixed this.

`<ion-card-header style="white-space: normal;">` could be placed in css file as well.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/GjDmJBNMdnoPiteAKpDB

Answer (score 16):

```
<ion-card-header text-wrap>
```

you can use text-wrap in other components too.

Comment: this should be the go-to solution for people using the newer versions of ionic imo, way cleaner than the accepted answer

Comment: Thank you @Ivaro18

Answer (score 0):

`white-space: normal;` is correct. But it should be placed on the header tag IE `h2`.  By default "ion-labels" (a class that can be injected into the DOM) have `white-space: nowrap;` applied to them. So setting `white-space: normal;` on the header tag selecting the ion-label tag through css will work.