# Text Wrapping in Ionic Header

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have been trying to wrap the text in my Ionic (v.3.19.0) project using the suggestions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221166/ionic-2-how-to-use-text-wrap-for-ion-card) and [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-text-wrap/8580/9), but when I run Xcode's simulator, the text does not wrap:

[image]

**index.html:**

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

<div class="bar bar-header bar-positive" style="height: 80px;" style="white-space: normal;">
    <h1 class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </h1>
</div>

<div class="bar bar-subheader bar-stable" style="height: 80px;" style="white-space: normal;">
    <h2 class="title">Phasellus sodales urna a
        <a href onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com', '_system');">tellus luctus sodales.</a>
        Donec non sagittis ex, a aliquam magna.</h2>
</div>
```

*Note: I have tried `text-wrap` and `style="white-space: normal;"`.*

I also tried changing the above code from `<div ...>` to `<ion-item text-wrap>` but it causes even more CSS issues:

[image]

*How can I resolve this issue?*

**EDIT:**

*Note: I am including the message that I receive when testing out the application in Xcode (v.8.1).*

> objc[72546]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Users/foo_user/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x110610998) and /Users/foo_user/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x11039ed38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   2017-12-16 14:31:43.147 TestApp[72546:7885253] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/foo_user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1234Z678-1234-123Y-1X34-123456789012/data/Containers/Data/Application/ZZ34Z678-1234-123W-VX34-UQ34567R9012/Library/Cookies/com.barcodescanner.binarycookies
>   2017-12-16 14:31:43.205 TestApp[72546:7885253] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.5.3 is starting.
>   2017-12-16 14:31:43.206 TestApp[72546:7885253] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
>   2017-12-16 14:31:43.257 TestApp[72546:7885253] Using UIWebView
>   2017-12-16 14:31:43.258 TestApp[72546:7885253] [CDVTimer][console] 0.039995ms
>   2017-12-16 14:31:43.258 TestApp[72546:7885253] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.098050ms
>   2017-12-16 14:31:43.259 TestApp[72546:7885253] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 0.923038ms
>   2017-12-16 14:31:43.260 TestApp[72546:7885253] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.064969ms
>   2017-12-16 14:31:43.260 TestApp[72546:7885253] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 1.860023ms
>   2017-12-16 14:31:44.256 TestApp[72546:7885253] Resetting plugins due to page load.
>   2017-12-16 14:31:44.388 TestApp[72546:7885253] ERROR Internal navigation rejected -  not set for url='about:blank'
>   2017-12-16 14:31:44.409 TestApp[72546:7885253] ERROR Internal navigation rejected -  not set for url='about:blank'
>   2017-12-16 14:31:44.755 TestApp[72546:7885253] Finished load of: file:///Users/foo_user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1234Z678-1234-123Y-1X34-123456789012/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/12345678-1SD4-123W-K34-1N3P567890J2/TestApp.app/www/index.html

Resources being used:

- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
- Angular 1.3
- Bootstrap 3.3.4

Comment: We can't really help without a live example. Keep in mind you don't have to reproduce all your app here, just the relevant part for the bug. Copy/paste the relevant ***final*** markup (the one produced by Ionic, not the source). and link all required resources from CDN sources to reproduce the problem here.

Comment: try `white-space: normal;` or the directive text-wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic does not currently support the following in its headers:

- `text-wrap`
- `style="white-space: normal;"`
- `white-space: normal;`

**Solution:**

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="item item-divider item-assertive" style="white-space: normal;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </div>
    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        <h2 class="title">Phasellus sodales urna a
        <a href onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com', '_system');">tellus luctus sodales</a>.
        Donec non sagittis ex, a aliquam magna.</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image: Text Wrapping Within the Card]

**Resource:**

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/9702